# If there was something else that's as fundamental other than time or space in a different universe, dimension, would we be able to conceptualize it?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology

If there was something else that's as fundamental other than time or space in a different universe, dimension, would we be able to conceptualize it?

Because language can only refer to something we've experienced or something that's analogous to something we've experienced, is it even possible to think or conceptualize something as fundamental as time or space ontologically without even experiencing it, or as it been deemed to be impossible, and why?

Comment: Per Kant's Critique of Judgment §59 the ideas of reason aka pure reason is just that absolutely no intuition commensurate with them can be given. To make sense of such idea of pure rationality we must have recourse to an alternative procedure, in which use is made of symbolic analogies as opposed to the proper sensible intuitions. However, analogy is a relatively arbitrary process, and hence each idea of reason can be symbolized metaphorically in a variety of ways, such as God, freedom and immortality. But Kant wouldn't claim these ideas as either his empirical or pure concepts of the mind...

Comment: Transfinite cardinals and modular tensor categories are neither something we experienced nor analogous to that. We do not experience extra dimensions of string theory, insides of black holes or the state of the universe at the Big Bang either. Yet we are capable of conceptualizing them abstractly. Some current proposals for quantum gravity already replace time and space with abstract structures that recover them as merely "emergent". So yes, we can conceptualize beyond Kant's "conditions of possibility of experience", although probably not without limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a view](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/possible-objects/#ModDim) that modality is itself dimensionalized like spacetime, such that modal facts, per object, depend on that object's "modal coordinates." So our own world would already have not just spacetime, but spacetime modality, as its whole superobject.

[Immanuel Kant said:](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3ACritique_of_Pure_Reason_1855_Meiklejohn_tr.djvu/213)

> Other forms of intuition besides those of space and time, other forms of understanding besides the discursive forms of thought, or of cognition by means of conceptions, we can neither imagine nor make intelligible to ourselves; and even if we could, they would still not belong to experience, which is the only mode of cognition by which objects are presented to u s.

I would imagine(!), though, that the principle *is* that of coordination, which we do understand more generally than *physical* spacetime. But adding higher dimensions to time and allowing for the relevant geometries to emerge does not seem to add in any entirely "new" geometrical concepts. We still could have regular and curved temporal patterns, etc. (notwithstanding the potential lack of a physical implementation for such exotic discourse). So likewise, adding in a whole new coordinate type-set (category?) doesn't necessarily seem as if it would mean adding in a new type/set of the generic coordinate idea *itself*. You might still be able to represent some basic Euclidean and basic non-Euclidean patterns, *in your physical space, on paper or a computer screen, or within your sheer imagination(!)*, as though they were images of patterns of the pure object alongside spacetime, here. Or you might even be able to integrate the conception *into* spacetime, as were space and time as separate systems of functions so united already.

But I'm not too confident in all that, to be sure. Maybe there is a level of geometrical abstraction such that if the third pure superobject satisfies some part of that abstraction concretely, then it would have significantly different lower-level geometrical properties, and might not even be open to harmonization with spacetime. I don't know about all *that*, to be sure, either; I don't know geometry, esp. higher-level geometry, especially well.

Comment: Anything fundamental different and unrelated to/from space, time?

Answer (score 1):

What you propose is done all the time by mathematical physicists, whose talents allow them to conceptualize things like four-dimensional spacetime, spacetime warpage, matter waves, gravity waves, neutrino handedness, electron degeneracy pressure, relativistic time dilation, and so on. Then others search for evidence for and against those conceptualizations. Occasionally, Nobel Prizes result.

To accomplish this, they use the language of mathematics, which experience has proven is the best tool we have at our disposal for the task. The mastery level required to play this game and get anywhere with it is far, far beyond the grasp of most humans like you and me.

Comment: Anything fundamental different and unrelated to/from space, time?

Comment: certainly. the models that are proposed to describe the world and fall by the wayside often contain fields and particles that do not exist and rules that do not apply to us; these are called *unphysical*  but as to the dimensionality of spacetime and our human ability to *experience* it, we are limited to 3 dimensions of space and one of time.